# Replace provided Maven dependency with local class

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

If I check my effective pom I will find the following entry:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.package.of.other.department</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

This comes from the parent pom that we have to use to let our software (bpmn processes) run on a company wide platform.

Now comes a hacky part. There will be a bigger change and we cannot use `someArtifact` anymore. Unfortunately that artifact gets called directly by all our processes (you design the process and configure the full qualified class name for an item) and can't just configure a different artifact, as that would most likely break a lot of the running processes.

The simple plan was to create a class with the same package name and with the same class name, remove every dependency to the original package and everything should work fine. During the tests I noticed that it doesn't use my new class but still the original one, most likely because it gets provided as dependency via the mandatory parent pom and for some reason prefers that over my local one.

Excluding a provided dependency from the parent pom doesn't seem to work that easily?! Any idea how I could solve my issue?

Comment: where is the new class located? In the same module that is used for testing?

Comment: @JimHawkins: The new class is part of the core of our processes, all our processes access the core for the logic.

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree` and check if someArtifact is not included transitively

Answer (score 1):

If the application is regular java, the class that will be load is the first class met in the classpath order.

If you use other runtime package dependency management, the strategy is different. As example you can adjust your import-package in OSGi to ensure the use a class contains in private-package.